# componentWillReceiveProps containing to many ifs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm still pretty new on React development, but I've already work on 3 big project using React+Redux and I see a pattern that I dislike a lot:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.params.type === TYPE_NEW_USER) {
      this.modalUsername = this.props.showPopup( < NewUsernamePopup onClose = {::this.closeUsernamePopup
        }
        />, USERNAME_POPUP_ID, true); 
      }
      if (this.state.kind !== nextProps.kind || this.state.filter !== nextProps.filter || this.state.hashtags !== nextProps.hashtags) {
        this.setState({
          results: [],
          loading: true,
          kind: nextProps.kind,
          filter: nextProps.filter,
          hashtags: nextProps.hashtags
        }, () => this.manageResults(nextProps.results, false));
      } else {
        this.manageResults(nextProps.results, true);
      }
      this.managePages(nextProps.paging);
}
```

I would like to avoid the ifs inside the componentWillReceiveProps. How do you handle it? We've analysed another project using Flux and callback registration. It looks like:

```
componentWillMount() { 
  EntityStore.on(EntityActions.ENTITIES_LOADED, this.getData.bind(this)); 
  EntityActions.entitiesLoaded(); 
}
```

The first event is emitted by the component, but afterwards the store emits the event and the component updates. Additionally a single store keeps its state and do not duplicate async calls if it already has the content. I personally like to avoid the ifs, but I do NOT want to lose Redux (its community and tools).

How would you add the current logic (ifs) inside the componentWillReceiveProps outside the component? I would like to handle the logic in a service layer and not inside the component.

I would definitely appreciate to read your opinion around this, because I've been struggling to find a solutions that fits.

Comment: Since the `this.setState((prevState, props) => { ... }` already has the access to `prevState` and `props`, and `componentWillReceiveProps` may be called even when no new props received https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops It seems better to `setState` when there's an actual change, rather than inside `componentwillreceiveprops `

Answer (score 1):

The redux approach is to put the logic into the actions/reducers.

So i don't know what your `manageResults` method does, but it is probably the piece of logic you want to move into a reducer so you won't need to call it from your component anymore.

So the `kind`,`filter` and `hashtags`variables should be updated from redux actions only.

Comment: I agree on the approach of moving logic to action/reducers. I did not create this component, and such logic (manage results) does not make sense to implemented in the component. But here the implementation is not important. I wanted to point the issue around the ifs inside **componentWillReceiveProps**. I would like to have a sort of callback.

Comment: Actually you do have this kind of callback, that's what i meant, this is in the reducers, by binding an action, it does invoke a callback.

I was trying to say, your differents "ifs" may be different actions/actions bindings (from the reducers).

Comment: Definitely, the logic around **manageResults** should be on the reducers side. However, I've seen this bad design pattern in all the react projects that I've joined contain such pattern..
In your opinion, when you should use component state instead of redux state (store)? I'm worried about modals, keeping scroll on place when loading on scroll among others.

Comment: Yes that's where you have to make a choice. In my opinion, the redux state should only be used when different components may need to access the property or when you want to keep the data between 2 refresh, otherwise, using ````componentWillReceiveProps```` is the best option for performance. I agree it doesn't looks neat, but try to think as a performance option :)

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr properly following redux best practices would eliminate some of these conditions, but I'd be more concerned about the overall design this snippet is revealing.

To address the individual lines:

```
if (nextProps.params.type === TYPE_NEW_USER) {
```

This looks like a redux action was passed to the component? If so, that's not great, only the reducers should care about action types.

```
this.modalUsername = this.props.showPopup(
```

The lifecycle hook `componentWillReceiveProps` is not the right place to initiate things like that, the resulting React component in an instance var also looks quite weird.

```
if (this.state.kind !== nextProps.kind || this.state.filter (etc.) ) {
```

If you have UI state in this component that is somehow dependant on the props coming from redux, these types of ifs are somewhat necessary, since you can't do it outside the component.

You are right to dislike this "pattern", which seems to reflect bad overall design. This component seems to be involved with "pages", "results", a username, and some ajax fetching with a loading flag. Can only speculate of course, but it seems like it's doing too much. The ajax request lifecycle should definitely be modelled in a reducer.

That said, the lifecycle hooks do often contain a bunch of ifs, since the reducers don't see routing and which components get mounted/unmounted, so that's where you have to react to changing props sometimes.

Comment: I do agree that it seems a bad design pattern, but I've encountered in 3 out of 3 projects that I've joined. The implementation here is not important, the code snippet was to point out a pattern that does not look right. In your opinion, when you should use component state instead of redux state (store)?
It seems that discerning between both is the solution to my headaches. Well, a big refactor is required because a lot of components are affected, but once I get an answer I'll tackle the issues.

Comment: Only use React component state when it's a) very volatile or purely UI related, like a button being hovered or not for example or b) somehow connected to interaction with real DOM elements or c) just not otherwise possible. Redux for everything else. This is my strategy at least, because then the whole smart container vs. dumb component approach really pays off.